# Openpyxl updating sheet and maintaining graphs and images

Tags: python, openpyxl

I just created a script with openpyxl to update a xlsx file that we usually update manually every month.

It work fine, but the new file lost all the graphs and images that were in the workbook. Is there a way to keep them?

Comment: The normal answer here, if you really need to keep existing content and you are on a platform that has Excel on it, is to use a scripting language to control Excel itself, rather than manipulating the files directly. Personally, I think it's simple enough to use VBA or VBScript, but if you want to stick with Python, give [xlwings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwings) a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

openpyxl version 2.5 will preserve charts in existing files.

Comment: Hi Charlie thanks for your response. Is there any way to preserve check box and dropdowns? Using Openpyxl .

Comment: @Charlie Clark I have a sheet where I update chart data range every two months. But now since the new version of openpyxl preserves previous charts, whenever I create a chart using updated data range, it overlays the previous chart in the sheet. Is there a way to delete the previous chart or just update the data range of existing chart?

Answer (score 0):

Use [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) instead, it works as a wrapper on pywin32 and can preserve the existing Excel graphs, pivot-tables, etc.