# copying .xlsx excel files with python while retaining formating/graphs

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I'm using xlrd, xlwt and xlutils to parse a large data file and import it to a pre existing excel sheet which has tables, graphs, equations, ect… The problem I'm having is, I can't seem to find a way to do this using xlsx excel files. When I create a copy of the pre existing excel sheet it forces me to convert it over to a xls file. This loses the ability to carry over some graphs and other formatting. Is there anyway to do this with python, or is it impossible? If it's the latter can you recommend me a language that can do this?

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, itay point you in the right direction to solve your problem; Use python to format data consistently then query the tidy data from your existing sheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl updating sheet and maintaining graphs and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214983/openpyxl-updating-sheet-and-maintaining-graphs-and-images)